# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC Identity issue

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating project with identity for login using password. when I publish project on production server and login and navigate to any link that page opens but after some time when I click on that same link it redirect to login page. I can't understand what should i do?
I have tried adding cookie policy options but doesn't work.

Comment: As far as I know, the identity will add the token into client cookie. The cookie contains the expire time. Could you please tell me how long it expired? After the cookie has expired, it will redirect to login page again.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the method that is creating token in your code. For token creation, it is likely that you are using Secret, Issuer, Audience.

Try to find where these values are stored in you program (probably in your appsettings.json file and injected into token provider class). It should look like this:

```
"tokenManagement": {
    "secret": "somesecretstring",
    "issuer": "optimify.cz",
    "audience": "optimify.cz",
    "accessExpiration": 300
  }
```

Behaviour you are describing is probably caused by access expiration value being too small (it is time until automatic disconnect in minutes). For start, try to set these value to some bigger integer.

You can also set token to refresh automatically like this - https://code-maze.com/using-refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-authentication/